# Separable and irreducible polynomial over $F$

Tags: galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, separable-extension

Let $f(x) \in F[X]$ a polynomial with degree 5 and Galois Group $S_5$. Show that $f(x)$ is separable and irreducible over $F$.

For irreducibility, I tried by contradiction
$$
f(x) = g(x) * h(x)
$$
where $g(x), h(x) \in  F[X]$ and $g(x)$ is irreduccible. I don't know how to continue, any help?

Comment: Well, you do want to make use of the Galois group, so perhaps consider some intermediate fields determined by $g$ and $h$? Actually, it suffices to consider the *very* transitive action of $S_5$ on the roots of $f$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen sorry, I can't understand, did u use any theorem or property?

Comment: The Galois group can be viwed as a group of permutations of the roots of $f$ (in a suitable extension of $F$). With less than $5$ roots you cannot have a group with more than $4!$ elements, hence the roots of our $f$ are all distinct (separability), and $G=S_5$ can actually permute all those roots. On the other hand, $G$ can only permute the roots of an irreducible factor within that same factor!